# how to send visual studio configuration options from cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I use CMake to configure and generate makefiles for a Microsoft MPI project that I build and run from Visual Studio 2017. In order to run the project, I need to modify the VS solution configuration settings. Under Configuration Settings->Debugging, I want to specify "Command" and  "Command Arguments" from the CMakeLists.txt. I can do this manually but I want to set it up from the CMakeLists.txt. Are there commands to do this?

Answer (score 4):

CMake 3.12 introduced two new target properties for that purpose: [VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND.html) and [VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS.html). Set these properties in the following way:

```
set_target_properties(targetName PROPERTIES 
    VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND "debug_command"
    VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS "debug_arguments")
```

Comment: 12 introduced only the first one, and 13 the second one.

Answer (score 2):

for anyone look for a solution on visual studio code with cmake extension, here is a solution:

change `program` field in `launch.json` to `${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}`,

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08yka.png)

ref:
[link](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/debugging.html#debugging)